# Simple for loop explanation

Tags: python

Why does this code...

```
alist = ['cat','dog','cow']
for item in alist:
        print alist
```

output

```
['cat', 'dog', 'cow']
['cat', 'dog', 'cow']
['cat', 'dog', 'cow']
```

While changing the `print` from `alist` to `item` outputs:

```
cat
dog
cow
```

I understand that when printing alist it will print the list as many times as there are elements in the list but I guess I just don't understand why this is different.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain the difference to me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a list - it contains cat, dog, and cow.
- Then you    say: for each thing in my list,  print my list.
- You have 3 things in your    list (cat, dog, and cow) so your list
  gets printed    3 times.
- When you    switch the statement to say `print item`    instead of
  `print alist` you    are saying for each thing in my list    print
  that thing -         so each    thing in your list gets printed,

  ie `cat, dog, cow.`

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a list, with a for loop like this

```
for item in alist:
```

Python, gets each and every element from `alist` and makes `item` refer to that element on every iteration. That is why you are getting one element at a time when you print `item`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I personally understand the logic of the for loop is this: "For each time one of the items in your list is read, your program will print/do something.

The list of items remains constant.

The first time you were just repeating the list for each entry position (index) in your list

The second time you were reading/reading each item in the list once per item in the list

---

```
for each_item in my list:
    #do something
```